# How to run npm install without changing working directory

Tags: node.js, npm, cd, npm-install

How to install dependencies for project without changing working directory to project root?

Curently you need to execute:

```
cd /my/project/root && npm install && cd -
```

I'm looking for an option like -C for Makefile so that I can:

```
npm install -C /my/project/root
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Posted on npm issue tracker: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16107

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A colleague of mine has found a way to do this (note that this is not documented in `npm help` but [online](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefix)):

```
npm install --prefix /my/project/root
```

Or the short version (only documented [online](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties))

```
npm install -C /my/project/root
```

Comment: It's documented [on this page](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefix)

Comment: @E.Sundin indeed. Should be documented in `npm help` though. From that page it also seems that there is a `-C` option  that does the same thing: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties